# Find nearest city on current location - Android

Tags: java, android, location

Hey I was wondering if you could help me.

I've basically got the users current location and ran a .getLocality() function from the geocoder object to display the city they're in. However if the users current location is in Middlesex how would I get it it say London??

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Errr, I guess you want a list of cities, then calculate the respective distances by using some coordinates in that city and display the top 5 closest?

Comment: Yeah I have a list of 50 cities each with their own coordinates. I just need to create something to find the nearest city.

Comment: Well, you can calculate the distances, then sort the list by shortest distance and display the first 5? I honestly don't see the difficulty if you already have this much data. At worst, the arbitrary point of one city will be slightly closer to the user than the other, meaning they will switch positions in the top 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may calculate the distance between your current locations latitude,longitude and passing lat & long of all the cities you have Now after that calculate which city has the least distance and show that.

```
public static double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
        double theta = lon1 - lon2;
        double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = rad2deg(dist);
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        return (dist);
    }

    public static  double deg2rad(double deg) {
        return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
    }
    public static double rad2deg(double rad) {
        return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
    }
```

Comment: I have a boundary box of each city giving me a radius. How do I implement this into that?